# gzip -t output "gzip: filename.gz: extra field of X bytes ignored"

Tags: gzip

I have a bunch of .gz files I'm checking the integrity after data transfer with gzip -t -v file
the output I'm getting is

```
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
....
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
gzip: C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1_2.fq.gz: extra field of 6 bytes ignored
OK
```

What do these repeated lines indicate and how I get just the final OK as output?

Comment: Could you `gzip -t` the files before the transfer? How were the `.gz` files created? Edit your post to add information,  don't respond via comments.

Comment: How were the files "data transferred"?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and there is nothing wrong with the files. It's just that they are [bgzip](https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html) files and not gzip files. Bgzip has some extra fields that gzip doesn't know about:

> The BGZF format written by bgzip is described in the SAM format specification available from http://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf.
> It makes use of a gzip feature which allows compressed files to be concatenated. The input data is divided into blocks which are no larger than 64 kilobytes both before and after compression (including compression headers). Each block is compressed into a gzip file. The gzip header includes an extra sub-field with identifier 'BC' and the length of the compressed block, including all headers.

So you can just ignore those messages, or you can remove the `-v` option which isn't needed anyway or you can use `bgzip -t` instead of `gzip -t`.